# How to create a contract which would delegate XTZs and receive rewards?

Tags: smart-contracts, baker, smartpy, rewards

I am trying to write a contract that receives rewards from the baker using a default entry point and should only allow me to change the baker from a different entry point.

I am using the smartpy tool to write a contract.

```
import smartpy as sp

class DelegateAndRewards(sp.Contract):
    
    def __init__(self,admin):
        self.init(admin = admin)
    
    @sp.entry_point
    def default(self):
        sp.verify(sp.amount > sp.mutez(0))
    
    @sp.entry_point
    def setDelegation(self,params):
        sp.verify(sp.sender == self.data.admin)
        sp.set_delegate(params.baker)
    
@sp.add_test(name="test")

def test():
     obj = DelegateAndRewards(admin = sp.address("tz1a4UNywaxaAfh2LRBP2UugQTeCVcLCn5Sa"))
     scenario = sp.test_scenario()
     scenario += obj
```

This contract gets originated (KT1Qk5To61kToEbfPPbsaCvAE8xt3fDMHF6B) but fails at invocation of "setDelegation" entry point.

If you change the name of the "default" entry point to something like "getRewardsFromBaker" (KT1B3J5EHQM92GZH9hRJjAn7Rab16unLoHLx). Things would work fine but I am not sure whether the baker would be able to transfer rewards. If yes then how?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the failed operation at https://better-call.dev/carthagenet/KT1Qk5To61kToEbfPPbsaCvAE8xt3fDMHF6B/operations, it seems the problem lies in the way you try to call the `getRewardsFromBaker` entrypoint. Which tool did you use to build this failed transaction?

Comment: Smartpy explorer

Comment: We've already discussed this several times. The SmartPy explorer doesn't take into account the presence or not of a default entry point which means that we use the path to the entry point from the root point which breaks when there is a default entry point. Also, as already said several times, KT1B3J5EHQM92GZH9hRJjAn7Rab16unLoHLx% getRewardsFromBaker can be used by bakers if they want to.

Comment: I am not sure how bakers who use automated rewards system will know that which entry point they should invoke to transfer rewards. If you say that they will search for an entry point which accepts 'Unit', I would argue there can be more than one entry point which would have parameters like that.

Comment: I see your point. My feeling was more that this will be a negotiation between you and your baker as may already happen today.